# Upgrade problem in Ubuntu 12.6 and 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am using DELL OPTIPLEX 3010, i3 3240 CPU, 3.40 GHZ, 4.00 GB RAM, 32 bit Windows 7.

When I have done the installation Ubuntu 12.06 or 14.04 alongwith Windows 7 the installation has been completed successfully but at the time of display off the "guest" login when I have used the following command and after restarting the machine the it has gone to "recovery mode" saying the "graphics is not supporting"

The command is:

```
gksudo gkedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Added:

```
allow-guest-false
```

After the above command to restart the lightdm

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Please help to sort out the problem. After upgrade or install any software the above problem also shows every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Android TV stick. It ran Ubuntu 12.04/12.06 very well, but it refused to show the desktop in Ubuntu 14.04. That's because Canonical made great changes in the Unity desktop and raised the minimum video requirements very high for 14.04.

You should change Ubuntu for Lubuntu or Xubuntu. These have lighter desktops than Ubuntu's Unity. They should work fine.